# Normalize string from webpage

Tags: python, string, encoding

Trying to normalize the string `"PartII\xa0I \x96 FINANCIAL\n INFORMATION"`. In general, all that should be left (once non utf-8 characters are excluded) are letters, numbers and dots. Therefore the expected output is `"PartII FINANCIAL INFORMATION"`. The text comes from [this](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000110465906023083/a06-8346_110q.htm) Sec form.

Solutions tried, where text is the ***string***:

1. `text.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')`
2. `unicodedata.normalize(decoding, text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this it will work for you:

```
text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

also if you need to remove `\n` use this:

```
text.replace('\n', "").encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Once you've encoded as `ascii` you can decode as `ascii` as well, no need to use `utf-8`. In fact you could just use the default for decoding.